# How to make a request get prior to all HTTP requests made with axios?

Tags: request, vuejs2, axios

I use VueJS with axios and Vuex. For each request that I make to the API, I always need to make a request prior to a URL to obtain a data.

This is my initial code, but it does not work for me. In fact, the browser hangs up.

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import axios from 'axios'
import VueAxios from 'vue-axios'
import store from './store'
import router from './router'
[...]

Vue.use(VueAxios, axios)
[...]

axios.defaults.baseURL = 'http://API_URL/api/v1'
axios.defaults.headers.get['Accept'] = 'application/json'
axios.defaults.headers.common['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
axios.interceptors.request.use(req => {
  if (store.state.user.user != null) {
    req.headers['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${store.state.user.user.jwtToken}`
    // INTERCEPTOR
    axios.get('http://OTHER_URL/verify_expire_token')
      .then(res => {
        if (res.data.response === 'error') {
          router.push('/')
        }
      })
  }
  return req
})
```

And in my `actions.js` (for my module `user`) I have all my HTTP request, for example `getUserInfo`:

```
import axios from 'axios'
import router from '@/router'

export default {
  [...]
  async getUserInfo ({ state, commit }, item) {
    axios.get('/users/info/' + item.codeUser)
      .then(res => {
        commit('setBasicInfo', res.data) // Set a state
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err))
  },
  [...]
}
```

But before I use this actions in some component and make call to the API `/users/info/`, I need to make a call to `http://OTHER_URL/verify_expire_token`.
That's why in my axios initializer I put an interceptor in the requests.

What is the best way to do it?

Comment: what's the _other_ request? I only see one.

Comment: on a side note, while `vue-axios` may look like a handy wrapper, it's usefulness in larger projects is rather limited. I would recommend writing your own API handling library to allow better separation of concerns.

Answer (score 0):

It's best to create your own `ApiHandler.js` file that handles all the remote stuff separately, and you can easily call from anywhere including vue components and vuex.

here is the how it would look (not tested or checked for errors or typos)

```
<script>
  import axios from 'axios';

  class ApiHandler{
    constructor(apiUrl) {
      this.axios = axios;
      this.apiUrl = apiUrl || '';  // this line allow passing a custom endpoint for testing
      this.config = {
        headers: { 'Cache-Control': 'no-cache' },  // can setup to prevent all caching
        baseURL: this.apiUrl,
      };
    }

    verifyToken() {
      // this assumes you are storing the token in your local store, of course this can come from anywhere
      let token = window.localStorage.getItem('token');

      // this assumes same api server, but you could handle that by having two different this.config objects
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        this.axios.get('/verifyToken', { token }, this.config)
          .then((response) => {
            // example of handling a custom API response
            if (response.code === 200) {
              resolve(true);
            } else {
              reject('Bad token');
            }
          })
          .catch((err) => {
            reject('internal error');
          });
      });

      // alternatively, you can skip creation of a new promise and just use `return this.axios.get`
      // this will not allow you to handle an error in a message with a success header (some APIs be like that)
    }

    getInfo(userId) {
      let payload = { userId }; // in case you need to pass data
      // chan promise requests, start by calling verify token
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        this.verifyToken()
          .then(() => {
            // then do the next call
            return this.axios.get('/users/info', {}, this.config)
          })
          .then((userInfo) => {
            // check if data is valid (see if it hase a name field or some other check if you like)
            if (userInfo && userInfo.name) {
              resolve(userInfo)
            } else {
              // return some error specific to request
              reject('User does not exist');
            }
          })
          .catch((err) => {
            reject(err);
          });
      });
    }
  }
</script>
```

you can then call this from anywhere by...

```
<script>
  import ApiHandler from '../lib/ApiHandler';
  const apiRequest = new ApiRequest();

  // and then anywhere in the component
  apiRequest.getInfo(112)
    .then((userInfo)=>{
      this.$set(this, 'userData', userData);
    })
    .catch(err => {
      if (typeof err === 'string'){
        this.errorMessage = err;
      } else {
        console.error(err);
      }
    })
</script>
```

As you can see I'm using custom Promise handlers in order to use my own `resolve` and `reject` functions, you can skip these and simplify the structure.

Even though I'm showing this intended for use in a component, I would abstract it further using actions. The component would call an action, which would call the apiHandler, which on response would push the new data into the vuex store, which would trigger an update (via vuex getters) on all components that use the data